# Changing Template of a Category Page and showing all the posts of the category

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

I am trying to change the template of the category page in Drupal 6.

What I am hoping to do is that when a certain category's link is clicked the template page that opens shows all the posts with the category.

I did create the page *page-taxonomy-term-tpl.php* which opens when I click on category but how do I personalize it by showing all the posts within the category?

Many Thanks.

Comment: what do you get now?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am just getting what homepage gets. All the posts listed with a sidebar. It has this line print $content which is just listing all the posts.